# How to use Http POST response data for md-table while getting request body from FormGroup?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have followed the plunker for [retrieving data through http](https://plnkr.co/edit/mjQbufh7cUynD6qhF5Ap?p=preview). I want to use FormControl to use input field in `POST` request body and display response in `md-table`.

The issue for me is ExampleDatabase and ExampleDatabaseSource are seperate classes. I know how to do regular http `POST` requests in the component using a seperate service but I don't know how to pass the POST body to ExampleDatabase to  do Http call or to pass the completed service response to ExampleDatabase so I can display in table?

I created an example component of what I mean:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {TestService} from './service'

@Component({
  selector: 'md-table-question',
  templateUrl: 'md-table-question.html',
})
export class MdTableQuestion {

  displayedColumns = ['id'];
  exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase | null;
  dataSource: ExampleDataSource | null;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _testService: TestService, private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleDatabase();
    this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this._fb.group({
            name:['', Validators.compose([
                Validators.required
                ])],
                ]},      
      );

// Here is the submit form that sends POST request. It comes from an ngSubmit event:
  submitForm(){
    let body= {name:this.form.get('name').value}
    this._testService.testRequest(body)
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
          })
  }
}
export interface test {
   id: number;
}

export class ExampleDatabase {
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<test[]> = new BehaviorSubject<test[]>([]);
  get data(): test[] {
// Not sure how to get data to here 
    // let data = 
    // return data;
  }
  constructor() {
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }
};

export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<test[]> {
    return this._exampleDatabase.dataChange;
  }
  disconnect() {}
}
}
```

Any help at all on how to do this would be great

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kzfB70QwhaMMLWkbuRiG?p=preview) of the problem

Comment: Can you add the code for `TestService`?

Comment: I tried to make this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kzfB70QwhaMMLWkbuRiG?p=preview) to demonstrate the problem. I used jsonplaceholder url that was just returning `{"id": 101}`. The idea is that the user inputs something into form. That input is passed to the body of Http Post request and sent. I have no idea how to display response in md-table or do the request with user input in `ExampleDatabase`? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A quick suggestion I'd like to do, is that you use your `service` like a true service, and implement a `mock` version of it to supply your application with example data for both testing and implementation purposes.

```
interface IExampleService {
    get(id: number): Observable<ExampleResult>
}

@Injectable() ExampleService implements IExampleService {
    get(id: number): Observable<ExampleResult> {
       return Observable.of( {} ) // empty object
    }
}

@Injectable() MockExampleService implements IExampleService {
    get(id: number): Observable<ExampleResult> {
       return blablabla // Return an observable with your expected test data.
    }
}
```

You can then switch this in your module `providers` section to load the mock instead of the real service.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. It will be useful for me in the future. The issue i'm having is not with the call but how to display response in md-table whilst using FormGroup to create request body